Configure Lambda function to handle EventBridge triggers seamlessly
I am new to AWS. My requirement is to trigger lambda function(spring-boot) at scheduled intervals to keep it warm . I am able to trigger lambda but it is giving error "com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.InvalidRequestEventException: The incoming event is not a valid request from Amazon API Gateway or an Application Load Balancer".
My lambda is exposing some Http endpoints which are working fine via postman and api gateway. What changes should I make in lambda that it should just keep warm and handle scheduled events seamlessly e.g just print Lambda Triggered rather this error ?
LambdaHandler.java
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
static {
    try {
        handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
        // If you are using HTTP APIs with the version 2.0 of the proxy model, use the getHttpApiV2ProxyHandler
        // method: handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getHttpApiV2ProxyHandler(Application.class);
    } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
        // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
    }
}



@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
    handler.proxyStream(input, output, context);
}
}

EventBridgeRule in SAM
MyEventBridgeRule:
 Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
   EventPattern: 
    source: 
    - "aws.events"
  ScheduleExpression: "cron(0/5 * * * ? *)"  # Example schedule expression
  State: ENABLED
  Targets:
    - Arn: !GetAtt ProductInfoSamFunction.Arn
      Id: "MyLambdaBridgeTarget"


You're using a different event type than what is expected. EventBridge calls Lambda async so it's not an APIGW/proxy type event. Here's a thread with some options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77481297/9172713
